# php function not returning expected output

Tags: php, json

I'm using php in Linux to use an API. I have problem with a code snippet.

```
$data1= $data->data_info;
$infoArr = array();
$j=1;
for ($i=0;$i<count($data1);$i++) {
    $infoArr['fruits']["info".$j]['key']=$key;
    $infoArr['fruits']["info".$j]['value']=$value;
    $j++;
}
```

When I run the API using curl in json format in Linux, I should get the output as:

`fruits:{"info1":{"key":1,"value":mango},"info2":{"key":2,"value":apple}}`

But I get the output as:

`fruits:{"info1":{"key":null,"value":null}}`

Comment: Where are you setting values for `$key` and `$value`?

Comment: Maybe a `foreach` loop is what you need

Comment: its in a particular API that I would be calling. This code snippet is just to format the output from the API

Comment: how would I use foreach here? Please help.

Comment: @user2509780 - Can you add a `var_dump($data1)` to the question?

Comment: Isn't there more code to provide?

Comment: var_dump wouldn't format it the way is required :) I tried that already

Comment: shouldnt it be better `for($i = 1; $i <= count($data1) ....` and using just $i instead of $j ?, by the way as this array seems small it doesn't matter too much but it's better to hold the `count()` in a variable and use `for($i = 0; $i < $dataCount ...` because if not you are counting the whole array in each loop

Comment: @user2509780 - You've provided some code, and we have no idea what the data you're working with looks like. var_dump would show that, and mean that we'd be able to provide help, rather than guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data1= $data->data_info;
$infoArr = array();
$j=1;
foreach ($data1 AS $key => $value) {
    $infoArr['fruits']["info".$j]['key']=$key;
    $infoArr['fruits']["info".$j]['value']=$value;
    $j++;
}
```

You need a foreach loop to set the temporary $key and $value variables.